# Changing the legend position when using Scale_Colour_Manual

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to change the legend position to the bottom, but I can't for some reason... I've tried `theme(legend.position="bottom")` 
but it didn't work...

```
n <- 20
s <- 5
f <- n - s
a_0 <- b_0 <- 2
a_post <- a_0 + s
b_post <- b_0 + f

post <- rbeta(n, a_post, b_post)

post_mean <- (s+2) / (s+f+4)
post_sd   <- sqrt((a_post * b_post) / (((a_post+b_post)^2) * (a_post+b_post+1)))


sample_stats <- function(n, alpha, beta) {
  sample <- rbeta(n, alpha, beta)
  return(c(sample_size = n, sample_mean = mean(sample), sample_sd = sd(sample)))
}
set.seed(12345)
df <- data.frame(t(sapply(2:500, get_stats, a_post, b_post)))
head(df)

library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(t(sapply(2:500, get_stats, a_post, b_post)))
head(df)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = sample_size, y = sample_sd, colour = "Sample S.D."), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = sample_size, y = sample_sd), colour = "#0039C7", alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_line(aes(x = sample_size, y = post_sd, colour = "Expected Value of S.D."), size = 1.1, linetype = 2) +
  labs(title = " Standard Deviation",
       y = "S.Ds", x = "Sample Size") +
  scale_color_manual("Legend", values = c("steelblue", "steelblue")) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Hi @Ahmed. Nice first question. Welcome to SO. Have you tried applying `theme(legend.position=c(x,y))`?

Answer (score 2):

You can place `theme_bw()` before `theme(legend.position="bottom")` like shown below:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = sample_size, y = sample_sd, colour = "Sample S.D."), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = sample_size, y = sample_sd), colour = "#0039C7", alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_line(aes(x = sample_size, y = post_sd, colour = "Expected Value of S.D."), size = 1.1, linetype = 2) +
  labs(title = " Standard Deviation",
       y = "S.Ds", x = "Sample Size") +
  scale_color_manual("Legend", values = c("steelblue", "steelblue")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

Comment: really appreciated, thats saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the legend.`position` after applying `theme_bw`. Otherwise the legend position is overwritten by the `theme_bw` default.

```r
n <- 20
s <- 5
f <- n - s
a_0 <- b_0 <- 2
a_post <- a_0 + s
b_post <- b_0 + f

post <- rbeta(n, a_post, b_post)

post_mean <- (s+2) / (s+f+4)
post_sd   <- sqrt((a_post * b_post) / (((a_post+b_post)^2) * (a_post+b_post+1)))


sample_stats <- function(n, alpha, beta) {
  sample <- rbeta(n, alpha, beta)
  return(c(sample_size = n, sample_mean = mean(sample), sample_sd = sd(sample)))
}
set.seed(12345)
#df <- data.frame(t(sapply(2:500, get_stats, a_post, b_post)))
df <- data.frame(t(sapply(2:500, sample_stats, a_post, b_post)))
head(df)
#>   sample_size sample_mean  sample_sd
#> 1           2   0.3660117 0.01100064
#> 2           3   0.2166538 0.08208572
#> 3           4   0.2727921 0.06715083
#> 4           5   0.3135043 0.06639387
#> 5           6   0.2571320 0.08528731
#> 6           7   0.3261430 0.11854048

library(ggplot2)
#df <- data.frame(t(sapply(2:500, get_stats, a_post, b_post)))
df <- data.frame(t(sapply(2:500, sample_stats, a_post, b_post)))
head(df)
#>   sample_size sample_mean  sample_sd
#> 1           2   0.3908063 0.21938429
#> 2           3   0.2979014 0.04337228
#> 3           4   0.2869401 0.10310720
#> 4           5   0.2918027 0.06315205
#> 5           6   0.3599353 0.13107339
#> 6           7   0.2393995 0.06767515

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = sample_size, y = sample_sd, colour = "Sample S.D."), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = sample_size, y = sample_sd), colour = "#0039C7", alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_line(aes(x = sample_size, y = post_sd, colour = "Expected Value of S.D."), size = 1.1, linetype = 2) +
  labs(title = " Standard Deviation",
       y = "S.Ds", x = "Sample Size") +
  scale_color_manual("Legend", values = c("steelblue", "steelblue")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>